# Packaging a Java web application: .war or symlinks to dependencies?

Tags: java, packaging

I would like to package my java web application http://kunagi.org/ for Ubuntu (and Debian).

Should the package install a `.war` file which contains all the required dependencies (`.jar` files)? Or should the package install the unpacked web application without `.jar` files and place symlinks into the `WEB-INF/libs/` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally there has been some friction between upstream and distribution level concerns with java packaging. Bundling dependencies has been one of the major points of contention. The security team particularly sees this as an unnecessary maintenance burden. Packages bundling libraries will likely be rejected from Debian.

Java webapp packaging policy in Debian is still evolving. There is currently a [Debian Enhancement Proposal (DEP) under discussion around this issue](http://dep.debian.net/deps/dep7/). It aims to

> propose a file layout, set of
>   conventions and best practices, and a 
>   supporting script interface for
>   packaging Java web applications 
>   (servlets) and deploying them in
>   containers.

This discussion is taking place on the [debian-java mailing list](http://lists.debian.org/debian-java). It's also probably the best place for you to ask further questions about Java packaging. I'm sure you will be able to find people willing to review your package for you there and most likely a sponsor willing to upload it.

Here are some furthur links that might be of interest:

- [Debian policy for Java](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/java-policy/index.html)
- [Tools for packaging Java apps and libraries in Debian](http://wiki.debian.org/Java/Packaging)
- [Debian Java packaging examples](http://pkg-java.alioth.debian.org/examples/)

Answer (score 0):

Why you should  use symlinks? You are more flexible with a .war Package, if you run the application in a Tomcat (or Jboss) cluster.

Comment: I thought, debian has a rule, which says that libraries should not be duplicated?